# How to reduce program time effort for boolean operation on two bytes stored in stack, using C?

Tags: c, stack, breadth-first-search

I have two struct elements a and b. I want to initialize them and create a function to and them and store them in a stack. I am pasting the code snippets below(just the required portion).I am not able to address them in stack. Assuming I have my push and pop functions ready(not pasting here)

```
  //this is my struct
  struct node {
       int name;
       bool covered;
       int value;
  };
```

i am adding my struct elements here. I create two struct variables a=1 and b=0

```
void add_nodes(int name) 
  {
   struct node* io = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   io->name = name;  
   io->covered = false;
   counter++;     
   //lstVertices[counter++] = io;
   push(io);   //for pushing into stack
}
```

In my and function, I am calling this function

```
void and_gate_2(int input_1, int input_2, int output)
{
    struct node * op;
    add_nodes(input_1);
    add_nodes(input_2);
    add_nodes(output);
    //not able to implement// 
}
```

such that in my main function, it should and a and b, and when I pop the last element of stack(i.e c), I should get 0 value of c. For this I need to pop a and b, and them and then push them again into stack, increase stack pointer by 4 and then push c. This would mean for ANDing 8 variables, I would need 8 push, then 8 pops and again 8 push. Wanted to know is there a solution that reduces the program runtime effort.

```
and_gate_2(a,b,c);
```

Comment: "For this I need to pop a and b, and them and then push them again into stack". So why can't you do exactly that?

Comment: that would increase my program running time to first pop all elements and AND them and again push them back. Wanted to know if there's any alternate solution

Comment: Well, that's not what you are saying or asking in your question. You said: "I am not able to implement that". Please edit your question to clarify exactly what it is you are unable to do.

Comment: I think the key here is: if you want to perform various operations on several items of data, why did you pick the stack ADT? It's unsuitable for such requirements by nature. It sounds a bit like you are trying to make an expression tree, in which case a binary tree ADT would make sense.

Comment: If you only allow pop and push, then there is no way of accessing the stack other than popping and re-pushing. But you can easily implement a "peek".

Comment: @kaylum I have modified my question. The objective was to improve program time.